# Can Magneto move molten steel?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Magneto has the ability to move steel, but can he move liquid or molten steel, so he can use it to burn buildings and humans?

Comment: I suppose it would be like moving magnetic liquid

Comment: For a nice demonstration that iron loses ferromagnetism when it melts, watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i2OVqWo9s0

Comment: People at [physics.se] Stack Exchange [say __no__](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59280/will-molten-iron-stick-to-a-magnet).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Aqueous steel solutions, yes (as per XCU canon)

In *X2: X-Men United*, we see Mystique inject a solution containing a high concentration of iron into the buttocks of prison guard Laurio:

[image]

[image]

Later, Magneto manipulates the iron in Laurio's bloodstream, with disastrous effects.

[image]

By the same token, he should be able to manipulate aqueous solutions of steel, given the iron concentration in most instances of steel.

As for liquefied or molten steel, I can't find any examples in any canon, but perhaps someone else's knowledge of obscure Marvel facts is better.  Based on out-of-universe reasoning alone, the answer would seem to be "no", via **tuskiomi's** nice answer.

Comment: I don't believe she injected him with liquid iron.

Comment: @Valorum : MAGNETO: *There's something different about you today, Mr. Laurio....Ah, there it is: too much iron in your blood.*

Comment: A liquid containing iron is not the same as liquid iron, leave alone molten iron. It could be an iron compound in solution or in suspension. Anyway, iron/steel becomes paramagnetic way below its melting point, requiring a higher magnetic flux to manipulate it. So in principle he should be able to move molten steel, if he can create a strong enough magnetic field.

Comment: @kolrabi - Magneto can definitely move metals that are not paramagnetic, anyway.

Comment: @Praxis - Iron in suspension, perhaps, but not liquid iron.

Comment: Too much iron is [very toxic, BTW.](http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/iron-supplement-oral-route-parenteral-route/side-effects/drg-20070148)

Comment: @Praxis aqueous iron is a far cry from molten steel.

Comment: As many others are pointing out, molten iron and a solution containing iron are not the same thing. Injecting someone with molten iron would end badly.

Comment: @tardigrade : The OP himself asks about "liquid or molten".  I've focused on liquid, not conflating the two.  What's the issue?

Comment: @tuskiomi : Sorry, but the original question asks about "liquid OR molten" and I'm answering about liquid.

Comment: @Praxis this is not liquid steel, it is aqueous iron oxide. http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-liquid-and-vs-aqueous/

Comment: If you can find me some steel that doesn't have a high iron content, you probably shouldn't be calling it steel anymore.

Comment: @tuskiomi : It seems I've spent too long on the theoretical side of physics (and when I say theoretical, I mean *theoretical*: string theory).  Although for the record, I was not discussing molten anything.  +1 to your answer, of course. :-D

Comment: @tuskiomi : I've edited my answer and also added a reference to your answer at the end.  I'm also perfectly happy if the OP shifts acceptance to yours.

Comment: @Praxis thanks for the edit! Sorry if I came off as rude, I'm sort of a stickler for facts.

Comment: @tuskiomi : No worries at all, and you weren't rude!  I like to hash things out until I know I'm wrong.  :-)

Answer (score 11):

I would say, no.

Here's why:
I'm assuming that magneto operates on the fact that he can disturb the natural magnetic field in a given space. I'm also assuming that he can't do any other funky things (extraneous powers). Iron, in a solid state, will take on magnetic fields easily, because the electrons are easily manipulated and aligned based on the orientation. Molten Iron, however, cannot conduct magnetic fields, as the electrons now have much more energy, and as a result, are only affected slightly by magnetic fields. By slightly, I mean that the most powerful magnets here on earth couldn't manipulate the liquid. And magneto probably couldn't, either.

Comment: Your physics is 'real-world' correct but this answer would be stronger with an in-universe source.

Comment: *Slightly* is good enough for Magneto, I'd think. +1 for science!

Comment: @Mazura, perhaps! But the hotter it gets, the less that iron reacts to a magnetic field, So it would have to be barely molten! any hotter, and he'll be dropping it like a hot (liquefied) potato!

Comment: Interesting paradox, since it is molten iron that is responsible for the generation of the Earth's magnetic field, which allows us all to live.

Comment: @AndrewMattson close, but it's actually *moving* the molten Iron that causes the field, and here is why. any time a charge is moving, there is a current, that is the definition of such. because the iron is very hot, it will ocasionally give up it's electrons, making the atom unbalanced. when a few of these start moving around,  a magnetic field is formed in correspondance with the charges moving.

Comment: I was aware of that, but the additional detail is useful for anyone who wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

By physics, Magneto should be unable to move iron that's above its Curie point (the temperature at which a phase transition renders the material non-magnetic).  This transition takes place many hundreds of degrees below the melting point of iron.  He *should* also be unable to move dissolved iron, which is ionized and hence lacks the electron properties to be ferromagnetic.

In comic canon, however, he has historically been able to move even the iron in the hemoglobin in his own blood (in order to levitate/fly), as well as things which ought to be non-magnetic (even metals other than iron and steel, never mind non-magnetic stainless alloys).  Even in the movies, his encounter with Laurio defied physics; either the iron was dissolved, and hence non-magnetic, or it was a suspension of non-magnetic stainless steel (else it would have corroded to a red or black color before it could be injected).

With both comics and movies ignoring physics, then, there's no reason Magneto couldn't move molten iron.  One could make a case that he's using induced current loops to provide the reaction, hence allowing him to move anything conductive (at the cost of a great energy expenditure and resistance heating from hysteresis losses).